# Temporarily stop Chrome tab switching visibility

Tags: c#, google-chrome

I work with Chrome using Selenium. The essence of the task is to switch to the window with the desired URL.

This code works. But at the same time, chrome flips pages like mad. I need to stop for a while all switching tabs in chrome until the desired tab is found. How to crank it up? thanks in advance

```
        string current_url = GetActiveTabUrl();

        // Here i need to stop the animation of switching tabs

        foreach (string k in Browser.WindowHandles)
        {
            Browser.SwitchTo().Window(k);

            if (Browser.Url.ToString().Contains(current_url))
            {
                // Here i need to bring everything back to normal
                string name = "Undefined";
                name = Browser.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='lot_title']")).GetAttribute("value").ToString();

                set_a_photo(chosePicture(name));

                break;
            }
        }
```